# Unable to get a page using Htmlunit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using below code

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    String url = "https://www.samsclub.com/sams/account/signin/login.jsp";

    try (final WebClient wc  = new WebClient())

    {             
        wc.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        wc.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        wc.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        //wc.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
        //wc.getOptions().setTimeout(0);
        final HtmlPage page = wc.getPage(url);
        System.out.println(page.asText());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But after the default timeout java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out exception is thrown any idea why i am not getting the login page?

Comment: Probably because your firewall is blocking the request, or because you're connected to the web through a proxy. Or because the server is really, really slow to answer.

Comment: @JBNizet there is no firewall, the site is working on browser so i dont think slowness of server is an issue

Answer (score 0):

This is really odd. I tried this on my computer and also failed (website on browser looks fine). I cannot even `wget` or `curl` this page.

I tried also changing agent etc. You can check it yourself with

```
curl -vvvv https://www.samsclub.com/sams/account/signin/login.jsp
```

So your program is not the only one that have problem with this page, I strongly belive that problem is walmart application not your code.

In order to solve this problem you can start debug mode in your browser, than check what really happens when you try to get page.